# Hive error :SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, hadoop, hive

I am trying to connect to Hadoop using a simple JDBC  Program and this is the error I am facing:

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

I have added the hive drivers to the classpath.

Comment: It would be much easier if you update your question stating your IDE, Operating System, JAVA and Hadoop version. Explain where are you receiving this message. For example, is this error in the console or in the IDE.? Are you using SLF4J in your application? Try to describe every information that could provide a better insight to your problem. By being more specific you help people understand and analyse your problem better and quicker!

Comment: I am using Eclipse Juno and Windows XP for my Client JDBC program.This is a Warning when I run the application in my Eclipse console.I am using sl4j as I had to add the jar file.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Juno and Windows XP for my Client JDBC program.This is a Warning when I run the application in my Eclipse console.I am using sl4j as I had to add the jar file.Also I read in some blogs that it's a warning thats not suppressed in some version of Maven.But I wanted to get rid of the warning also.